# Connecting to AWS using a different key than the one used to launch the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

This may be a stupid question but here it goes: **Can you SSH into your AWS instance if using a different key-pair than the one used to launch the instance?**

This seems a bit off because what if you need to connect to the instance from another computer? It seems very dangerous to send keys over the net so other machines can login into the instance.

Comment: That doesn't seem dangerous to me, after all didn't you download the first key from the 'net'?

Comment: True but you downloaded it from amazon's own server. Sending a security related file through, say e-mail, or any other way of sharing a file does not seem dangerous to you?

Comment: Idk, I guess I've never had 'noc list' caliber data to give it that much thought.  I didn't think it was too hard to revoke a key and add a  new one though.  Here'a a similar question that might help you http://serverfault.com/questions/300352/ec2-multiple-ssh-keys-for-an-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the other key-pairs' public keys into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. 
Please refer to on-line tutorials like : [Change Key Pairs on Aws Ec2 Instance](http://seabourneinc.com/2011/01/19/change-key-pairs-on-aws-ec2-instance/)